# How To Use Shared GTK+ and GLIB Libraries in a CMake Project

Tags: c++, cmake, gtk, shared-libraries, glib

I've got a project which was originally using a makefile which i'm now converting to a Cmake project to use with CLion. I need to import gtk+1.2.10 and glib-1.2.10 both of which are located in /usr/local. I have attempted to include them but all attempts have resulted in messagees saying it cannot find gtk/gtk.h. My CMakeList.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(src)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(Library "../usr/local")
include_directories(${Library})
include(FindPkgConfig)


add_custom_target(src COMMAND make -C ${src_SOURCE_DIR}
        CLION_EXE_DIR=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})


link_directories("/usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
set(glib_DIT "/usr/local/glib-1.2.10/lib/libgmodule.so")

find_package(GTK 1.2.10)
IF (glib-1.2.10_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${glib-1.2.10_INCLUDE_DIR})
ENDIF()

include_directories(/usr/local/glib-1.2.10/lib)
include_directories(/usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10/lib)
```

The MakeFile is

```
gcc -Bstatic -L /usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10/lib -L /usr/local/glib-1.2.10/lib -lgtk -lglib -I ../ -I /usr/local/glib-1.2.10/lib/glib/include -I /usr/local/glib-1.2.10/include/glib-1.2/ -I /usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10/include/gtk-1.2/
```

What can I do to be able to these libraries inside of CLion.

EDIT: I have created a p.c file called gtk with contents

```
prefix = /usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name:GTK
Description:WORKS FFS
Version:1.2.10
Cflags: -I{includedir}/gtk-1.2 -lgdk -l
Libs: -L{libsdir} -Lgtk
```

And my current cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(src C)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/local/gtk+-1.2.10/bin")


include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(gtk REQUIRED gtk)
```

Even with these changes the outcome is the same

Comment: [FindGTK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindGTK.html) and [FindPkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindPkgConfig.html) might help.

Comment: I added pkg_check_modules(GLIB glib-1.2.10) but it gave me no package found. Am I mean to give it a directory anywhere?

Comment: Check the pkg-config name, it's probably not `glib-1.2.10`… for glib 2.x it's `glib-2.0`, for glib-1.x it's probably just `glib`. It should match a file in `/usr/local/glib-1.2.10/pkgconfig`.

Comment: The problem is I dont have any files called pkgconfig in glib or gtk directory. I only have other directories in there.

Comment: That's `pkg-config`, it's in a `bin` directory, and I don't think it's in a glib installation, that's a separate thing. What does `which pkg-config` returns ?

Comment: BTW you look completely clueless about how to write a CMakeLists.txt and seems to just try random stuff. Please take the time to read a CMake tutorial. I also wonder what kind of outdated application you are migrating that uses GTK+ 1.2 (released 18 years go) but where you try to set the language to C++11...

Comment: which pkg-config returns /usr/bin/pkg-config. I'm using GTK 1.2 because working on this arm emulator called Komodo which was originally released i think in 99.

Comment: Thanks, I found https://github.com/UoMCS/komodo . You'll have much more work than that, as that's a whole project to migrate from one build system to another. I also saw in the [configure.in](https://github.com/UoMCS/komodo/blob/master/configure.in) that there's a configuration switch to use GTK+ 2, so maybe that works and you don't need to use GTK+ 1.2. Not having CMake integration doesn't mean you can't use CLion as an editor. I find having to change your build system to adapt to your IDE a bit weird. The tools are there to serve you, not the other way around.

Comment: As a side-note, several open source projects are migrating to a build system simpler than CMake, [Meson](http://mesonbuild.com/). That's what GTK+, GStreamer and Mesa for example are going toward (GTK+ 4 will use meson instead of autotools).

Comment: Thing is the current build system thats in place does not work thats why currently i'm just using a makefile with the gcc commands i listed earlier. I thought cmake was the only way i can get CLion to have proper linting and autocomplete for the libraries